# Naming Unconvention

Tags: knowledge, wordplay, visual, lateral-thinking

This week's puzzle follows the usual convention: circles which represent as yet unknown categories.

One tile has been placed to help - your task is to place the others and explain why.

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is a nice one :) The Venn diagram should be resolved like this:

> [image: Resolved Venn diagram]

For the reason that:

> Any name appearing in the *left*-hand circle is an **anagram of the name of a country**.
>
>  And any name appearing in the *right*-hand circle is an **anagram of the name of a capital city**.
>
>  Because of this, CHAIN (CHINA), KANYE (KENYA) and ENEMY (YEMEN) appear in the left-only section; ANIMAL (MANILA, Philippines), LOOS (OSLO, Norway) and ANNE IV (VIENNA, Austria) appear in the right-only section; and LIAM (both MALI and LIMA, Peru) appears in both!

Comment: >! simultaneously I am im/depressed at your quick responses

Comment: @AlteringIntegral Haha :) This one happens to be 'right up my street' as far as the subject matter goes. Plus I've been sick in bed with Covid for days, and so I've been on the site fairly frequently looking for an entertainment lift! Thanks for this one - much appreciated...

Comment: so to compound it you're doing these on your sickbed!!  Get better soon